# Test convergence of $\int_0^1x^p(\ln^q(\frac{1}{x}))dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Test convergence of $\int_0^1x^p(\ln^q(\frac{1}{x}))dx$

My work.

Let $\ln(x^{-1})=y$

then integral becomes $\int_\infty^0-e^{-yp-y}y^qdy$ = $\int_0^\infty e^{-yp-y}y^qdy$=$\int_0^1 e^{-yp-y}y^qdy$ + $\int_1^\infty e^{-yp-y}y^qdy$ ​

How  continue ?I want  to bring these  in the form $\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^a}$ and $\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x^a}$ where I know where integral is convergent. I saw similar questions but I couldn't understand.

I want to solve this question without using Gamma function.

I am getting $(\frac{1}{p+1})^{q+1}\int_0^\infty z^qe^{-z}dz $ which is convergent when $q>−1$ but can't get values of $p$ from here.

Comment: @OliverDiaz That answer uses Gamma function so not.

Comment: You should edit the requirement that you want to solve this without using the gamma function in your question, then the question may be re-opened.

Comment: Also I want to find values of $p,q$ such that integral is convergent.

Comment: 'Similar' questions compute integral

Comment: I am getting $(\frac{1}{p+1})^{q+1}\int_0^\infty z^qe^{-z}dz$ which is convergent when $q>-1$ but can't get values of $p$  @OliverDiaz

Answer (score 1):

With the change of variables you suggested you transform the integral of interest into $\int^\infty_0e^{-(1+p)y}y^q\,dy$. As the integrand $f_{p,q}(x):=x^p\log^q(1/x)$ is nonnegative on $(0,1)$ for all $p,q$, $f_{p,q}\in L_1(0,1)$ iff $F_{p, q}(y)=e^{-(p+1)y}y^q\in L_1((0,\infty))$ and $I_{p,q}=\int^\infty_0F_{p,q} =\int^1_0 f_{p,q}$.

Notice that for $F_{p,q}$ to be integrable, it is necessary that $p+1>0$. Under this assumption, notice that

1. $0\leq F_{p,q}(y) < y^q$ for all $y>0$
2. $F_{p,q}(y)\leq e^{-(p+1)y}$ if $q<0$ and $y\geq1$.
3. If $q>0$, $F_{p,q}(y)\leq e^{-(p+1)y/2}$ for all $y$ large enough ($\lim_{y\rightarrow\infty}y^qe^{-(p+1)y/2}=0$).
4. $F_{p,q}(y)>e^{-(p+1)}y^q$ for $0<y<1$

- By (4), the integral $I_{p,q}$ diverges to $\infty$    if $q\leq -1$
- By (1) and (2), the integral $I_{p,q}$ converges for $-1<q\leq 0$; by (3), the integral $I_{p,q}$ converges for $q>0$.